# User generates mzroute.js error

Tags: error-handling

Somebody know what is this

```
 https://srv.mzcdn.com/mzroute.js
```

used for? Google told me practically nothing, but one of my users generated about 800 error messages with this address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it came from a browser's extension from superfish.com

Not sure if it's malicious but be careful

EDIT : based on some several new search some others extension generate the same error and most of them are considered as crapware

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion?  I too experienced a ton of error messages from one particular user, and I see that one of them involved a request to https://srv.mzcdn.com/mzapp.js?16015&mzid=63&uuid=undefined.  So far this is the only page I've turned up that has anything meaningful about this domain.  I visited superfish.com but couldn't find anything about browser extensions, or indicating they had a conneciton to mzcdn.com.

Comment: Not really sure if it came from superfish, it can be several others site, also superfish.com has changed since last time I visited. Just take a look at the https://srv.mzcdn.com/mzroute.js script and you will see many others site in the blacklist array...

Comment: So what made you say on 2013 Apr 24 that it came from a browser's extension from superfish.com?

Comment: Cose the previous superfish.com offer to install a chrome extension that I tryed and immediately got the same error...

Answer (score 3):

I have similar problem, my web application code was corrupted (only in Chrome) because something has automatically added these two scripts into head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://srv.mzcdn.com/mzapp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://srv.mzcdn.com/scripts/_wildcard.js?384463"></script>
```

In my case, this was added by chrome extension "Smiley Bar for Facebook", so you or one of your users have this or similar extension installed... definitely uninstall this crap